# Not getting the correct value on using react-hook-form with a counter

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a very simple implementation of a counter. On form submit, the value of the counter is always "0". The counter value is changing but I am not sure why on form submit, the counter value is 0.

I am not sure, what I am missing. Thank you for your time.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-matan-ybjf81?file=/src/App.js)

Below is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(0);

  const decrement = () => {
    setQuantity((prev) => (prev === 0 ? 0 : prev - 1));
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setQuantity((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const formSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
        <button type="button" onClick={decrement}>
          -
        </button>
        <input type="number" value={quantity} {...register("quantity")} />
        <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
          +
        </button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code not works due to useForm use register(`onChange,name,onBlur`) for input and you are using quantity of useSate instead of `useForm` defaultValues

If you want to do using useForm then you can do by using `setValue,getValues` and `defaultValues` in this way

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      quantity: 0
    }
  });

  const decrement = () => {
    setValue(
      "quantity",
      getValues("quantity") === 0 ? 0 : getValues("quantity") - 1
    );
  };

  const increment = () => {
    setValue("quantity", getValues("quantity") + 1);
  };

  const formSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Counter</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}>
        <button type="button" onClick={decrement}>
          -
        </button>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={getValues("quantity")}
          {...register("quantity")}
        />
        <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
          +
        </button>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out

```
export default function App() {

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setQuantity(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Result
    alert(quantity);
  };

  return (
    ....
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ....
        <input type="number" value={quantity} onChange={handleChange} />
        ....
      </form>
    ....
  );
}
```

Furthermore details [Here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)